# Breeze query a knockout observable array multiple times

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4, breeze

I'm stuck in this point and can't continue.

I'm creating a ViewModel for a search form in this way:

```
var viewModel = new SearchViewModel("Api/Vehicle", "Vehicles");
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Later when user click the find button, it fires the find method (simplified here):

```
self.Find = function (predicate) {
     var query = breeze.EntityQuery
         .from(self.actionName)
         .where(predicate);

     var promisse = self.manager.executeQuery(query)
          .then(querySucceeded)
          .fail(queryFailed);
 }
```

The query* methods only put the data in a Knockout.js observable array:

```
function querySucceeded(data) {
    data.results.forEach(function (item) {
        self.results.push(item);
    });

    return true;
}

function queryFailed(error) {
    var erroboj = { message: error.message };
    self.errors.push(erroboj);
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that querySucceeded is never called and the data never update for Knockout.js fire the databinding.

What I'm doing wrong?

---

Here is the ViewModel. A bit uncomplete and fuzzy yet.
I think I didn't understand correctly the breeze query promisses:

```
/*global $, jQuery, ko, breeze, bootstrap */

function SearchViewModel(serviceName, actionName) {
    "use strict";
    var self = this;

    self.serviceName = serviceName;
    self.actionName = actionName;
    self.errors = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.results = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.CreateEntity = function (entityTypeName) {
        var entityType = self.manager.metadataStore.getEntityType(entityTypeName),
            newEntity = entityType.createEntity();
        return self.manager.addEntity(newEntity);
    };

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        // Here the function I want to run
        data.results.forEach(function (item) {
            self.results.push(item);
        });

        return true;
    }

    function queryFailed(error) {
        var erroboj = { message: error.message };
        self.errors.push(erroboj);
        return false;
    }

    function addError(errorMessage) {
        var erroobj = { message: errorMessage };
        self.errors.push(erroobj);
    }

    function NoFilterDefined(Condition) {
        var s = "Find(): Funcao Filter() not implemented:";
        addError(s);
        Condition = null;
        throw new Error(s);
    }

    try {
        self.Filter = NoFilterDefined;

        self.Find = function () {
            debugger;
            var Condition = breeze.Predicate;
            var predicate;

            self.errors.removeAll();
            try {
                predicate = self.Filter(Condition);
            } catch (errorf) {
                var sf = "Find(): Error calling Filter() in {actionName}: {error}";
                sf = sf.replace("{error}", errorf.message);
                sf = sf.replace("{actionName}", predicate.toString());
                addError(sf);
                throw new Error(sf);
            }

            var query = breeze.EntityQuery
                .from(self.actionName)
                .where(predicate);

            try {
                debugger;
                var promisse = self.manager.executeQuery(query)
                    .then(querySucceeded)
                    .fail(queryFailed);

                // Here I suppose the .then(querySucceeded) already was called
            } catch (errore) {
                var se = "Find(): Erro calling query in {actionName}: {error}";
                se = se.replace("{error}", errore.message);
                se = se.replace("{actionName}", self.actionName);
                addError(se);
                throw new Error(se);
            }
        };

        self.FetchMetadata = function () {
            //self.manager.fetchMetadata() // not working?
            //   .fail(self.queryFailed);
            var query = breeze.EntityQuery
                    .from(actionName)
                    .where("1", "==", "0"); // Just to get metadata

            var execution = self.manager.executeQuery(query);
            execution.then(function (data) {
                data = null;
            });
            return true;
        };

        self.SetParameters = function (parameters) {
            self.parameter = ko.observable(parameters);
        };

        self.store = new breeze.MetadataStore(); // define metadataStore for all managers
        self.manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
            serviceName: self.serviceName,
            metadataStore: self.store
        });

    } catch (error) {
        var erroboj = { message: error.message };
        self.Errors.push(erroboj);
    }
}

try {
    // Uncomment //debugger to debug this script. Use Visual Studio an IE to debug.
    //debugger;

    var viewModel = new SearchViewModel("Api/Vehicle", "Vehicles");
    var parameter = {
        Id: "AAB-1113",
        Type: "CIF"
    };

    viewModel.SetParameters(parameter);

    viewModel.Filter = function (Condition) {
        "use strict";
        var self = this;
        var where = Condition.create("Type", "==", self.parameter.Type);

        if (parameter.Id !== null) {
            where = where.and("Id", "contains", self.parameter.Id);
        }

        return where;
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

} catch (error) {
    alert("Erro de codigo:".concat(error.message));
}
```

Comment: Could you post your view model?

Answer (score 4):

The most important question: why is your `querySucceeded` method not called at all?  I assume your `queryFailed` is not called either? One or the other should have been hit.

Have you verified with a debugger that neither method is called? Are you sure that there are any query results from the server? I'd start there by copying the HTTP GET request from the network traffic log and replaying it in a browser address bar. Only after you're sure that the server is returning something would I move on to the processing of query results.

---

**Note: I just saw the complete ViewModel below your problem statement.**

I wrote my reply before seeing the full VM and almost started over. But I'm keeping my original answer because *it's important to know how to tackle a mystery*, not just answer it.

The problem is almost certainly with your predicate. I'll bet you see results if you remove the `where(...)` clause. My bet is that the predicate sets a condition that is never true and therefore you never have any results to display.

Inside `self.Find` you initialize the predicate to the Breeze `Predicate` constructor. I don't think you ever want to do that. You probably want to create a new instance.

You seem to want to create an "identity condition" - a condition that is always true. This seems a bit clever to me. The utility and implementation of `NoFilterDefined` is also a mystery to me ... but now I'm straying far from the matter at hand.

Why not just keep let `self.Filter()` remain `null` until there are actual filter conditions? Then build your query appropriately, perhaps as follows:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from(self.actionName);
var predicate = self.Filter();
if (predicate) { query = query.where(predicate); }
```

Checkout this [introduction to predicates](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-filter).

---

Your **`querySucceeded`** seems like it should work although I'd prefer a few changes. For example, I wouldn't push query result items into the KO observableArray one-by-one. Why not just use the query results array?

```
function querySucceeded(data) {
    self.results(data.results);
};
```

If you're worried about something messing with the `data.results` array before your query method returns (why?), you can copy it first

`self.results(data.results.slice());`

Lesser points:

- I strongly recommend moving persistence concerns such as these out of the ViewModel and into a helper component such as a `dataservice` or `datacontext` as [described here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/share-entitymanager).
- You don't need any of that `fetchMetadata` business as far as I can tell. Breeze fetches metadata implicitly upon the EntityManager's first query. You can pre-fetch Metadata if necessary ([see `MetadataStore.fetchMetadata`](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html#method_fetchMetadata)) but there's no obvious need for it here.
- should your `self.Find` method return the promise to the caller?
- why does your `querySucceeded` return `true`?
- should you clear `self.results([])` in `self.Find`  before you execute the query? I usually do.
- why is `self.errors` in `queryFailed` a KO observableArray. You are pushing an error message onto an array of error messages ... an array that you cleared at the beginning of the method. Why an array? Why not a simple KO observable?